# If $Y$ and $(X_1, X_2)$ are correlated, is it necessarily true that $\operatorname{cor}(Y, X_1)>0$ and $\operatorname{cor}(Y, X_2)>0$?

Tags: probability

If $Y$ and $(X_1, X_2)$ are correlated, is it necessarily true that $\operatorname{cor}(Y, X_1)>0$ and $\operatorname{cor}(Y, X_2)>0$? In other words, does correlation on the joint space imply correlation on the marginals?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand but I think the answer is no. If $Y = \beta \times X_1 + \epsilon$ then $Y$ would be correlated with $(X_1, X_2)$ but not with $X_2$.

Comment: @roundsquare even if $X_2 = \gamma \times X_1 + \epsilon$ ?

Comment: @SagarM in that case, yeah, $Y$ and $X_2$ would be correlated. But my point was to say that $Y$ and $X_2$ need not necessarily be correlated.

Comment: In addition to roundsquare's correct answer, pls also note that there is no reason to think the correlation must be positive (it can be negative).